# Testing Android app built for arm64

Tags: android

So far, I've been able to deploy and test Android applications on Android Emulator on my PC.

This was possible because both APK was built for x86 architecture and my Ubuntu is running on x86 PC.

Now, I have Android application as APK build for arm64-v8a and I cannot even run AVD for this architecture on my Ubuntu because I'm getting:

> PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host.

What are my options here?

1. I thought perhaps there are Ubuntu VMs compiled for arm64 that can run on x86 host?
2. Or perhaps docker image for virtualization.

The best would be to have docker image with emulator for arm64 already installed.

I currently have no access to a real phone to test APK. I would like also to test APK locally, so using remote test labs (like https://developer.samsung.com/remote-test-lab) is not an option here.

Comment: No response 7 months ago, not good. There's this, https://console.firebase.google.com/?pli=1 and I don't know what this means, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/arm64-visual-studio-is-officially-here/ for the issue. So far noting as I can see because you still can't emulate 64. Pixel phone inbound I guess.

Comment: It is definitely possible to run the ARM64 emulator on x86-64 Linux. However, I have never done it, and can't tell where your problem is. The most obvious thing to check is how old a version of Ubuntu you're running: it's conceivable that it's too old for the Android SDK and emulator you're using.